# My Todo print does not text align to the left when I build my Menu

Tags: html, css, svelte

> `
> import Menu from './Menu.svelte'
> export let name;
>
> ## Todo App
>
> fesfse
>
> div {
> text-align: -50px;
> display: grid;
> grid-template:
>           "nav content" min-content
>   }
>
> .content {
> grid-area: content;
> }
>
> `

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

All I would use and if I just want the text aligned to the left is

```
text-align: left;
```

so change your

```
text-align: -50px;
```

and it should work :)